# org-structure-template-alist: Chasing a ghost entry

Tags: org-mode

yesterday I realize that the entries in my `org-structure-template-alist` were not working. I found that it was due to the update to Org 9.2, and I decided to comment the personalized structures in my `.emacs`.

The problem is that, even after commenting the code, I'm getting the following warning:

```
Warning (org): 
Please update the entries of `org-structure-template-alist'.

In Org 9.2 the format was changed from something like

    ("s" "#+BEGIN_SRC ?\n#+END_SRC")

to something like

    ("s" . "src")

Please refer to the documentation of `org-structure-template-alist'.

The following entries must be updated:

(("n" "#+BEGIN_NOTES\n?\n#+END_NOTES"))
```

I rechecked my `.emacs`, but strangely **I don't have a note structure defined**. I've looked for it in `org.el` and `org-tempo.el` but no luck!

I don know what is happening, Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I assume you've installed `org-mode` from the package manager. This looks like a mismatch of versions of individual files. Try recompiling `org-mode` (or everything to be sure) to see whether that's the case. If you generate autoload files manually, you should generate them again as well.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.

The problem is with Org-Mode 9.2+ and the variable `org-structure-template-alist`. It has changed in version 9.2: https://orgmode.org/Changes.html

The culprit on my system was in the file `ox-reveal.el` (on my machine in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/ox-reveal-20161027.226/ox-reveal.el` )

I've replaced the code at the end to look like this

```
;; Register auto-completion for speaker notes.
(when org-reveal-note-key-char
  (add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
                '(org-reveal-note-key-char . "NOTES")))
```

and recompiled the ELISP code. Of course, if a fixed version of ox-reveal is published, make sure to use it.

If you want to use the old style shortcuts, you need to

```
(require 'org-tempo)
```

Comment: Awesome answer. It looks like ox-reveal is being abandoned in favor of org-re-reveal, a fork compatible with org-mode 9.2.